# Where are obj files for ndk-stack in androidTest packages

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-testing, object-files, ndk-stack

I'm implementing a few instrumented tests for a module (which is packaged in a `aar` archive, not `apk`) library I'm working on. The module is written partially in Java and partially in C.

Sadly a crash is occurring while running my tests and executing native code; I want to symbolicate the crash dump with `ndk-stack` in order to see the actual culprit and investigate my problem.

I know that those files should be in the object directory **obj/**, right inside the project directory, specifically:

```
$PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/<ABI>
```

The problem is that they simply aren't there. Where are they? How can I let the *androidTest* related tasks generate them or showing me where they are? What am I missing?

The project structure is the following:

```
MyProject
 |_ :app (a single button application which integrates the library)
 |_ :myLibrary (the actual library I'm working on and testing)
    |_ java
    |  |_ my.package.name
    |  |_ my.package.name (androidTest) <- a test here crashes
    |  |_ my.package.name (test)
    |_ cpp
       |_ my native files
```

Comment: I take it your **not using** `Android Studio Gradle` build (so **not** `CMake` or `ndkBuild`). Can you elaborate a little on your build system ?

Comment: I'm actually using plain Android Studio Gradle build. To be more specific I use `ndkBuild`. I've written a custom `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` files to manage the shared object build. To execute the tests I use the standard IDE tools (e.g. the "play button" on single test cases or test class).

Comment: A typical path to `.obj` files (`ndkBuild`) would be `...\android-project\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs-debug\SDL2\src` why have you not used your operating system search for `*.o` files ?

Comment: That's super weird, I had performed a `find` (I am running macOS) in the whole project directory but didn't found anything with the `.o` extension. Now I've manually moved in the directory you specified and there they are! Specifically the path is: `$PROJECT_PATH/myLibrary/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj`.

Comment: cool, yes that's the place I would expect,anything else you need ?

Comment: Nope, that's it, I've successfully symbolicated my crash dump, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments it appeared that the correct path to find debug object symbols is:

```
$PROJECT_PATH/myLibrary/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
```